# Shutdown hook of Java process doesn't trigger in gradle daemon

Tags: java, gradle

I have a socket server application.
This application shutdown server and unbinding from port inside of standard Java shutdown hook when process is stopping :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook());
```

I use application gradle plugin to run it from command line:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.ServerLauncher"
```

But when I run application from gradle:

```
./gradlew :server:run
```

And then close application with ctrl+z my shutdown hook doesn't trigger.

I guess it's because gradle starts it's own process which starts java process, but it looks like java process doesn't receive shutdown signal.

Comment: did you try to stop it using the --stop command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found solution, to prevent this behavior I need to say gradle not to run it's daemon thread passing this command line argument

```
./gradlew :server:run --no-daemon
```

Answer (score 3):

Current Gradle versions use Gradle daemon by default. What actually happens is that after you press Ctrl+C (I think you meant it instead of Ctrl+Z) you don't just terminate your application, you terminate the whole Gradle process. It takes about 10 seconds. Shutdown hooks are executed, but with a delay, and as Gradle is disconnected from console output, you won't see any messages.

Currently the simplest workaround is to add `--no-daemon` switch.

There is an enhancement proposed to Gradle to fix this behaviour. You can vote for it: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1128

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to keep using the daemon as it offers various advantages.

Then there is a possible solution to really stop your application by sending it TERM signal rather than stopping the Gradle process that initiated its execution. Just look at the documentation of `kill` and `jps` (or simple `ps`).